# PHP Des Encryption from CSharp

Tags: c#, php

I'm porting the Following C# Encryption logic to php, i tried using OPENSSL to port the encryption but its giving me a weird error, i have no idea what im doing wrong maybe OPENSSL fault, padding? not sure

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static ICryptoTransform DES;
        public static DESCryptoServiceProvider Crypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        public static MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        public static string encyrptedMessage;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Crypto.BlockSize = 64;
            Crypto.FeedbackSize = 8;
            Crypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            Crypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            //Your code goes here
            DES = Crypto.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("L)#!&8@*"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CodeFast"));
            CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

    // Set up streams and encrypt
            byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("yes");
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, DES, mode);
            cryptoStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
            byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Position = 0;
            memStream.Read(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);

    // Encode the encrypted message as base64 string
            string encryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessageBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace encryption;

class DESCrypto{

    private $key;
    private $iv;

    public function __construct(string $key, ?string $iv){
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->iv = utf8_encode($iv);
    }

    public function encrypt(string $text): string {
        return openssl_encrypt($text,"DES-ECB",$this->key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$this->iv);
    }

    public function decrypt(string $text): string {
        return openssl_decrypt($text,"DES-ECB",$this->key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$this->iv);
    }
}
```

the C# Code is working fine meanwhile the php one returning the following error

```
Warning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is 4 bytes long which is longer than the 0 expected by selected cipher
Warning: openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 4 bytes long which is longer than the 0 expected by selected cipher
```

Comment: It looks like the IV passed is 4 bytes long which is longer than the 0 expected by selected cipher. Also unless you want to convert a UTF8 string into an ISO8859-1 string `utf8_decode()` is corrupting your data. [and the encode function will corrupt it in the reverse] But without seeing example code that actually calls these functions, ideally with example input and output, it's hard to say exactly what you're doing wrong here.

Comment: But your problem is likely that DES-ECB doesn't take an IV at all, probably because of how much ECB sucks as a block cipher mode. [please don't choose this for new code. DES either, for that matter.] I would wager that the C# library simply discards it, whereas OpenSSL complains. Additionally, static IVs such as you seem to have hard-coded into your C# code [along with a key? oops?] are also a bad idea and defeat the purpose of IVs in the first place.

Comment: How about a complete sample dataset (plaintext, key, ciphertext) from your C# implementation to test any PHP-function, thanks.